# Create array of unique items from DataTable

Tags: c#, arrays

I'd like to create an array of unique items from a datatable column. I know how to create a dataview...

```
DataView view = new DataView(table);
DataTable distinctValues = view.ToTable(true, "Column1", "Column2" ...);
```

Is it a similar approach for an array? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ

```
DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();
//......
string[] uniqueItems = myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                                  .Select(r=> r.Field<string>("MyColumn"))
                                  .Distinct()
                                  .ToArray();
```

;